# Proper syntax to run CLIREG32?

Tags: c++, vb6, dcom, clireg32

I'm trying to install a legacy VB6 client on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine that can talk to a DCOM server written in Visual C++.  I know I need to run `CLIREG32` and pass it the `.VBR` file as a parameter.  I'm trying it like this:

```
clireg32 myvbrfilehere.vbr -s <ip address> -d -l
```

It seems to run without a hitch, but I think I should be able to search the registry and see the IP address i entered as a parameter.  So something tells me I'm missing something during this command.  (I've also tried adding `-t mytypelibrary.tlb` but that doesn't help either)

Any thoughts on using this ancient technology?  I'm not in a position to rebuild everything right now.  I'm starting to get desperate...

Thanks

Comment: Just the fact the server was written in c++ doesn't validate the [tag:c++] tag for this question IMHO.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor so you at least have something to look at.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least limited information in Microsoft article Q155939.

([Archived copy](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/155/Q155939/).)

Paraphrasing the useful parts:

> **Q155939: HOWTO: Use Clireg32.exe for Remote Automation**
>
> ```
> Article: Q155939
> Last Modified: 31-JUL-1999
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> The information in this article applies to:
>
> - Microsoft Visual FoxPro for Windows, versions 5.0, 6.0 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> SUMMARY
> =======
>
> This article provides an explanation of Clireg32.exe and how it is used for
> remote automation.
>
> MORE INFORMATION
> ================
>
> The Clireg32.exe component allows you to register an OLE server (.exe) remotely.
> It differs from the Remote Automation Connection Manager (RacMan) in that the
> server does not need to be located on the machine registering it. The Setup
> Wizard handles the maintenance of registering remote servers for you.
>
> NOTE: Remote servers and Clireg files are stored in the \Windows\Olesrv\
> directory, which is similar to Visual Basic if it is installed via the Setup
> Wizard.
>
> The Clireg32.exe program takes a number of parameters. The only required one is
> the name of the .vbr file (generated with the server during build):
>
>   Clireg32 myexesvr.vbr
>
> In order to fully register a remote server, you must provide the network name,
> network protocol, and security access. Clireg32 prompts you with a dialog box if
> these options are not passed. For a list of all the parameters, simply execute
> Clireg32.exe by itself.
> ```
>
> Copyright Microsoft Corporation 1986-2002.